# Laravel Sanctum API Auth issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

Here's my issue:
I've put my API into production mode, and when I make a request to it using Sanctum on the backend and Axios on the frontend, I encounter a 419 error under certain circumstances. For example, it depends on the value of the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN` (if I set it to localhost:3000, I get a 419 error and no cookie, whereas if I set it to just localhost, it works but still no cookie).

The major problem is that during development, with `SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=localhost:3000`, everything works with cookies. Additionally, the `APP_URL` is different between the production and development versions.

I'm sharing my various pages below.

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbusername
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://domain.fr

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SESSION_DOMAIN = domain.fr
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=localhost:3000
```

cors.php

```
  'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' =>  ['*', 'localhost:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

sanctum.php

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

axios request

```
            const formInscription = store.getState().User.usersInputs;
                  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
                  const getToken = await axios.get('http://domain.fr/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(async response => {
                      await axios.post(
                          'http://domain.fr/api/add_user',
                          formInscription
                      );
                  })

                
                  store.dispatch(postUserDataSuccess());
                }
```

Update :
When I comment

```
'api' => [
           // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
```

It works but I have no cookie :(

Comment: In `production`, shouldn't your `STATEFUL_DOMAIN` be `domain.fr`?

Comment: @UnderDog , No, but it looks like it; there are no subdomains.